# How to create a multilevel (numbers/alphabetical/Roman) list in Wiki?

Tags: wiki, wikipedia, wiki-markup

I am writing some documentation about our algorithm and it's flow and I am doing it in Wiki.
Please advise how can I create a multilevel list with

```
level 1 = 1,2,3...
level 2 = a,b,c...
level 3 = i,ii,iii...
level 4 = I,II,III...
```

I know I can use #, ## but I need a mixed one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Template:ordered list, it give you the ability to create a specific lists. For example if you need to make lower alpha style, use this code:

```
{{ordered list|type=lower-alpha
 | Hello
 | Word
}}
```

It will produce the following:

```
a.Hello
b.Word
```

See the other styles here: https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/generate.html#lists

For more; see this page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:List#Changing_the_list_type